# Do apps generated with yeoman need node.js in production

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

Let's say I am using yeoman to scaffold an application.Now this scaffolding needs node.js.Using node.js  during development is completely fine with me.However, do we need node.js in production too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't. If you are using the official angular generator, it produces a static build (in the dist subdirectory) that can be served with any http server, such as Apache or Nginx.

Comment: but the backend is a node app. How can  you avoid this?

Comment: If the backend is written in Node (say Express) then of course you are going to need Node in production too.